# UCWA refresh Oauth token with grant_type=password

Tags: lync, ucwa

I'm trying to refresh an OAuth token using Lync UCWA, following the examples here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn356686.aspx#sectionSection3

The example in their docs uses grant_type urn:microsoft.rtc:anonmeeting, but I am using a grant_type=password.  My client is successfully authenticating against the /WebTicket/oauthtoken endpoint at first and I receive the access_token just fine.

After a few hours, I need to refresh the OAuth token by posting to /WebTicket/oauthtoken again with the parameters of:

```
grant_type=password
username=$my_username
password=$my_password
ms_rtc_renew=$access_token (cwt=AA....)
```

That is returning a status 400 though, with an error: invalid_request and a comment in the headers "No valid security token".  The value I'm putting into ms_rtc_renew is the same value I'm using in all of my headers to other endpoints, 'Authorization' : ['Bearer $access_token'], so the token is working alright.

I have made sure that I'm using a header of Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded when posting to the /WebTicket/oauthtoken endpoint, and that I'm urlencoding the data before posting.

Has anyone else been able to refresh an OAuth token using Lync UCWA 1.0 and a grant_type=password?  Any experienced UCWA devs out there recognize what I'm missing in my post to refresh the token?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ms_rtc_renew is specific to the anonymous meeting grant type.  In that same documentation it mentions:

> Refreshing a token for authenticated users is the same flow as acquiring a new token.

This is the correct train of thought, but it does omit a few key pieces of information.  If you are interested in keeping the original UCWA application valid, it is necessary to provide the **same information** when executing the POST request on applications otherwise it will be creating a new application.

**Expanded Answer**

When you reach a point that the UCWA application is returning 404 to requests and indicating that the current OAuth token is invalid it is necessary to renew.  Following the steps of [KeyTasks-CreateApplication](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication), request a new token on step #5.  At this point take the new token and replace the **Authorization** header and attempt to make the failed request.

If that does not work, consider re-creating the application (step #9) using the same data (UserAgent, EndpointId, Culture).  You would need to replace any saved Json data because the application Url might change between instances (*not entirely certain*).

Comment: Thanks for the reply ShelbyZ.  Sorry I'm still not clear, is there a different key/value that UCWA is looking for when I try to renew a token that I got from using grant_type = password?

Something like grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w&access_token=cwt... ?

Comment: Expanded my original fragment a bit, let me know if you that makes any sense.

Comment: Alright, so as far I understand it then, you're just suggesting that at the end of the 8 hours I should just create a new application instead of renewing the access_token I already have.  That's a perfectly acceptable solution, but it seems to go against the spirit of the UCWA docs.  No problem, it's UCWA 1.0 for a reason!

Comment: I think you are missing a key point that the non-anonymous grant types don't get the special renew parameter when requesting an OAuth token.  The point being that the OAuth token expires and it _should_ be possible to request a new new one and replace the header and continue UCWA'n.  The suggestion to create a new application would be in the case where the OAuth token expires and the application is also cleaned up.  When you provide identical parameters upon creation the server should re-establish that application.

Comment: I'm tracking, ShelbyZ.  The wording in the documentation is awkward, "The lifetime of a token is eight (8) hours for authenticated users. The client application should monitor the expiration time and refresh the token as required."  I completely understand where you're coming from now, just need the documentation to read, 'the client application should request a new token when the original expires'.  Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: It is a bit confusing and the testing of it is much worse!